# Java EE Framework to condition the privileges of the logged user

Tags: jakarta-ee, frameworks

I need to develop an application in Java EE technology. One of the the tasks is :
Every user having a special profile should get a different view. It means that I have many functionalities but not everyone has everything.

So I dont know if it exists a framework which might help me to condition the view according to the user ( the profile ).

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, using **Spring Security** Framework was a pretty good solution.

After configuring the framework, you need to define your namespace for the Spring Security Facelets Tag Library :

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
```

Then you can use the tag :

```
<sec:authorize></sec:authorize>
```

as follow :

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</sec:authorize>
```

At this way users owning any of the 2 roles is able to see "Lorem ipsum....".

And there are more possible attributes. For more details you can check the Spring Security [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-webflow-reference/html/ch13s09.html).